# How to convert a text file to 2D array using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I have a text file :

> ABCDEFGHIJKL.MN

My Expectation output:
AB
CD
EF
GH
IJ
KL

```
I tried this :
f = open("test.txt", "r")
output_list = []
for rec in f:
    chars = list(rec.strip())
    output_list.append(chars)
    print(chars)
```

But It return : ['A', 'B', 'C', ....]

Any Idea, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a 2D array from a text with multiple lines,
please try the following:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    output_list = []
    for rec in f.read().splitlines():
        rec = rec[:-3]  # remove 3 last characters
        list = [rec[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(rec), 2)]
        output_list.append(list)

print output_list
```

where "test.txt" looks like:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKL.MN
OPQRSTUVWX-YZ
```

and the output:

```
[['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL'], ['OP', 'QR', 'ST', 'UV', 'WX']]
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. It works. But I forget to write the problem, that I dont want to include 2 last word. My expectation result : AB CD EF GH IJ KL . Not include MN. Any idea please. Thanks @tshiono

Comment: I've modified the code accordingly. Please uncomment the line `list.pop(-1)` to exclude the last element. Note that it assumes the length of each line are even numbers. Otherwise it will better to remove two characters *before* splitting into a list.

Comment: But, I have . before 2 last character. ABCDEFGHIJKL.MN . I want to remove 3 last character (.MN) . Help please

Comment: It is a new information not mentioned in the original post. Is it okay to remove three characters at the end of lines regardless of the character? Or do you prefer to "remove characters after dot" or similar ?

Comment: Ya. I will edit the post. I prefer to remove the 3 last characters first then convert it.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer accordingly. I hope it will meet your requirements.

Comment: Then I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.